# NameError: name 'python3' is not defined [Jenkins]

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a very simple task to do.
I've written a script `job.sh` to invoke a python script

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 pythonscript/script.py
```

I want this `script.py` to run every hour, so I took help of Jenkins and configured `job.sh` in the project.

Running `job.sh` standalone works fine, but when the same runs in Jenkins it shows an error :

```
NameError: name 'python3' is not defined
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Content inside script.py:

```
for i in range(30):
        print("PRINTING FROM PYTHON SCRIPT")
```

Have two questions :

```
1) How to resolve the above error
2) The Jenkins job runs in a different folder lets say `(jenkins/jobs/job131.sh)` and my `script.py` is somewhere else `(pythonscript/script.sh)`. How to give the absolute path to my script so that `job.sh` will invoke it without any issue.
```

Comment: Did you happen to check which version of Python is on jenkins?

Comment: @Sashi How to ...... ?

Comment: Couldnt write it as a comment, so I wrote it as an answer. Try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1

Option 1:

Try to change the shebang so that it can run with a specific version of Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
```

Option 2:

Try to run it as python2 instead of python3

```
 python pythonscript/script.py
```

### Question 2

You can use `pwd` to get the absolute path to your script. And you could then add that to the jenkins script.

Comment: That's resolved now. Thanks! But Q2 is not resolved yet. Can you help?

Comment: Ah sorry somehow missed that question. What is your file structure like? I would normally use a relative path.

Comment: Regular ubuntu file structure. Jenkins jobs run deep inside /bin or /tmp. My scripts are in a different folder.

Comment: Updated the answer, try it out :)

Comment: Thanks man. Everything works well, jenkins has found the file and attempted to run it. But I'm getting the error : can't find '__main__' module in script.py

Comment: Not sure how your script is organized. Btw might be helpful if you create a new question for this. Since the problem now is probably with your script itself

Comment: That's great :)